# Correct usage of 'had'

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect

I was recently studying a paragraph in which I came across a sentence, which was below:

> The British king, Charles I, had inherited a very difficult financial situation from his father.

However, I don't understand why 'had' is being used here. My understanding is that had is used only in past perfect tense, where there are two events in past and we use had to signify that event that finished before the second event started. So I modified the above sentence like below:

> The British king, Charles I, inherited a very difficult financial situation from his father.

Is the modified sentence correct? Please help me to understand.

Comment: Your sentence is correct by itself. But the first version must be part of a story about a king with challenges. He struggled during his reign because he **had** inherited his father's mess before that. The past perfect sets that cause further in the past.

Comment: If you convert my version to present simple, it becomes:``The British king, Charles I, inherits a very difficult financial situation from his father.``, which seems totally wrong. That's why I can't believe my version to be correct too.

Comment: If the rest of the paragraph was talking about events _later_ in his reign, it makes sense to refer to the _start_ of his reign as being in the past. Your version describes what happened at the time that he came to the throne.

Comment: "The British king, Charles I, inherits a very difficult financial situation from his father." could be fine depending on the context. It's impossible to judge this in isolation without knowing its place.

Comment: I CV'd because this sentence is presented without any context, and only context can determine whether the past perfect or simple past would be appropriate. (This is also a very simple question that would be more appropriate for ELL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I don't understand why 'had' is being used here.

It is because the past perfect is used to describe and set the background/context to what follows.

You have omitted to say what follows, but you will find that, in all likelihood, it will be in the simple past and be the focus/theme of the passage.